# GPU Implementation of adaptiveThreshold() in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, gpu

Is there `GPU` implementation of `adaptiveThreshold()` in `opencv`.
I am not able to find it opencv reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. You only have the function `threshold()`.